# PHP exec() runs but aborts early

Tags: php, unix, web, webserver

I'm having to generate some images as part of a simulation project I'm working on. These need to be generated based on user input. I'm using PHP's `exec` function and it works like a charm for the most part. However, my program is exiting with exit code 134 which, as far as I know, means it is being aborted. As far as I know, I've set all the appropriate permissions. Could it be a memory issue? Any help is appreciated. I can provide more details if necessary.

Comment: Are you running the script from CLI or the browser? You may have a timeout issue.

Comment: unix? if you run `exec($command)` add to command ` 2>&1` and will see all errors from `$command` in output

Comment: I'm running it from the browser. I figure it is some kind of timeout issue, but I'm not sure how to investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PHP exec command it means it is not the PHP Error and I searched the shell/bash error and found that:

```
Exit code 134 means your program was aborted (received SIGABRT), 
perhaps as a result of a failed assertion.
```

If you program with assertions and want to debug, I recommend the following redirect stderr to stdout as:

```
dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO);
```